# Is there any sdk to log exceptions, events and errors in production app?

Tags: android, logging, error-handling, sdk, production

I want to catch all the un expected/undesirable events in my app during production. I want something which can send a error log file to server and I can easily read it through a web application. Do you know anything of this sort ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flurry analytics

crashlytics

They will give you the logs and errors in production app..I think this will suits you well

Answer (score 0):

Use Mint to get every exception log or Use MonkeyTalk for all logging for your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all unexpected/undesirable Exceptions.

Please put this line in your those classes, where you need to get `Log`.

```
ErrorReporter.getInstance().Init(YOURACTIVITY.this);
```

You can use this `ErrorReporter.Class`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;

import com.example.demogetlog.R;

public class ErrorReporter implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

     String VersionName;
     String PackageName;
     String FilePath;
     String PhoneModel;
     String AndroidVersion;
     String Board;
     String Brand;
    // String CPU_ABI;
     String Device;
     String Display;
     String FingerPrint;
     String Host; 
     String ID;
     String Manufacturer;
     String Model;
     String Product;
     String Tags;
     long Time;
     String Type;
     String User; 

     private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler PreviousHandler;
     private static ErrorReporter    S_mInstance;
     private Context       CurContext;

     public void Init( Context context )
     {
      PreviousHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
      Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( this );  
      RecoltInformations( context );
      CurContext = context;
     }

     public long getAvailableInternalMemorySize() { 
            File path = Environment.getDataDirectory(); 
            StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath()); 
            long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize(); 
            long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks(); 
            return availableBlocks * blockSize; 
        } 

     public long getTotalInternalMemorySize() { 
            File path = Environment.getDataDirectory(); 
            StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath()); 
            long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize(); 
            long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount(); 
            return totalBlocks * blockSize; 
        } 
     void RecoltInformations( Context context )
     {
      PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            try
            {
             PackageInfo pi;
                // Version
                pi = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
                VersionName = pi.versionName;
                // Package name
                PackageName = pi.packageName;
                // Files dir for storing the stack traces
                FilePath = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
                // Device model
                PhoneModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
                // Android version
                AndroidVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

                Board = android.os.Build.BOARD;
                Brand  = android.os.Build.BRAND;
                //CPU_ABI = android.os.Build.;
                Device  = android.os.Build.DEVICE;
                Display = android.os.Build.DISPLAY;
                FingerPrint = android.os.Build.FINGERPRINT;
             Host = android.os.Build.HOST;
             ID = android.os.Build.ID;
             //Manufacturer = android.os.Build.;
             Model = android.os.Build.MODEL;
             Product = android.os.Build.PRODUCT;
             Tags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
             Time = android.os.Build.TIME;
             Type = android.os.Build.TYPE;
             User = android.os.Build.USER;

            }
            catch (NameNotFoundException e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }

     public String CreateInformationString()
     {
      String ReturnVal = "";
      ReturnVal += "Version : " + VersionName;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Package : " + PackageName;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "FilePath : " + FilePath;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Phone Model" + PhoneModel;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Android Version : " + AndroidVersion;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Board : " + Board;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Brand : " + Brand;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Device : " + Device;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Display : " + Display;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Finger Print : " + FingerPrint;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Host : " + Host;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "ID : " + ID;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Model : " + Model;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Product : " + Product;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Tags : " + Tags;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Time : " + Time;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Type : " + Type;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "User : " + User;
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Total Internal memory : " + getTotalInternalMemorySize();
      ReturnVal += "\n";
      ReturnVal += "Available Internal memory : " + getAvailableInternalMemorySize();
      ReturnVal += "\n";

      return ReturnVal;
     }


    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
          String Report = "";
          Date CurDate = new Date();
          Report += "Error Report collected on : " + CurDate.toString();
          Report += "\n";
          Report += "\n";
          Report += "Informations :";
          Report += "\n";
          Report += "==============";
          Report += "\n";
          Report += "\n";
          Report += CreateInformationString();

          Report += "\n\n";
          Report += "Stack : \n";
          Report += "======= \n";
          final Writer result = new StringWriter();
          final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
          e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
          String stacktrace = result.toString();
          Report += stacktrace;

          Report += "\n";
          Report += "Cause : \n";
          Report += "======= \n";

          // If the exception was thrown in a background thread inside
          // AsyncTask, then the actual exception can be found with getCause
          Throwable cause = e.getCause();
          while (cause != null)
          {
           cause.printStackTrace( printWriter );
           Report += result.toString();
           cause = cause.getCause();
          }
          printWriter.close();
          Report += "****  End of current Report ***";
          SaveAsFile(Report);
          //SendErrorMail( Report );
          CheckErrorAndSendMail(CurContext);
          PreviousHandler.uncaughtException(thread, e);
         }

         static ErrorReporter getInstance()
         {
          if ( S_mInstance == null )
           S_mInstance = new ErrorReporter();
          return S_mInstance;

    }

         private void SendErrorMail( Context _context, String ErrorContent )
         {
          Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          String subject = _context.getResources().getString( R.string.CrashReport_MailSubject );
          String body = _context.getResources().getString( R.string.CrashReport_MailBody ) +
           "\n\n"+
           ErrorContent+
           "\n\n";
          sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] {"YOURMAILID"});
          sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
          sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
          sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
          _context.startActivity( Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Title: Please choose for Email") );
         }
         private void SaveAsFile( String ErrorContent )
         {
          try
          {
           Random generator = new Random();
           int random = generator.nextInt(99999);
           String FileName = "stack-" + random + ".stacktrace";
           FileOutputStream trace = CurContext.openFileOutput( FileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           trace.write(ErrorContent.getBytes());
           trace.close();
          }
          catch(IOException ioe) {
           // ...
          }
         }

         private String[] GetErrorFileList()
         {
          File dir = new File( FilePath + "/");
                // Try to create the files folder if it doesn't exist
                dir.mkdir();
                // Filter for ".stacktrace" files
                FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
                        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                                return name.endsWith(".stacktrace");
                        }
                };
                return dir.list(filter);
         }
         private boolean bIsThereAnyErrorFile()
         {
          return GetErrorFileList().length > 0;
         }
         public void CheckErrorAndSendMail(Context _context )
         {
          try
          {
           if ( bIsThereAnyErrorFile() )
           {
            String WholeErrorText = "";
            String[] ErrorFileList = GetErrorFileList();
            int curIndex = 0;
            // We limit the number of crash reports to send ( in order not to be too slow )
            final int MaxSendMail = 50;
            for ( String curString : ErrorFileList )
            {
             if ( curIndex++ <= MaxSendMail )
             {
              WholeErrorText+="New Trace collected :\n";
              WholeErrorText+="=====================\n ";
              String filePath = FilePath + "/" + curString;
              BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
              String line;
              while (( line = input.readLine()) != null)
              {
               WholeErrorText += line + "\n";
              }
              input.close();
             }

             // DELETE FILES !!!!
             File curFile = new File( FilePath + "/" + curString );
             curFile.delete();
            }
            SendErrorMail( _context , WholeErrorText );
           }
          }
          catch( Exception e )
          {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
         }

}
```